# C++ Crypto: Part 1- Hash

Tags: c++, cryptography, authentication, server, client

Looking around for modern Crypto libraries.
Could not find anything good.

I know I probably did this all wrong so work with me here. There will be four different reviews for four structures that build on each other:

1. Hashing
2. [Hashed Key](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/248417/507)
3. [Password Key](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/248418/507)
4. [Salted Challenge Response](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/248419/507)

This is the hashing code and provides a simple wrapper around SHA-1 and SHA-256 but the pattern is simple enough that we can expand it for other hashing mechanisms.

The data structures and implementation presented in these questions are based on [RFC2104](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2104) and this post on [codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22118/C-Class-Implementation-of-HMAC-SHA).

### Usage Example:

```
DigestStore<Sha1>    hash;    // <- destination of hash
Sha1                 hasher;

hasher.hash("This string can be hashsed", hash);
```

### hash.h

```
#ifndef THORS_ANVIL_CRYPTO_HASH_H
#define THORS_ANVIL_CRYPTO_HASH_H

#ifdef  __APPLE__
#define COMMON_DIGEST_FOR_OPENSSL
#include <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>
#define THOR_SHA1(data, len, dst)       CC_SHA1(data, len, dst)
#define THOR_SHA256(data, len, dst)     CC_SHA256(data, len, dst)
#else
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#define THOR_SHA1(data, len, dst)       SHA1(data, len, dst)
#define THOR_SHA256(data, len, dst)     SHA256(data, len, dst)
#endif

#include <string>
#include <array>

//
// Wrapper for sha1 and sha256 hashing algorithms
//
// Provides a simple wrapper class with the appropriates types and size
// for the resulting "digest" object. Also provides several type safe
// versions of the hashing algorithm to allow multiple know types to
// be safely hashed.

namespace ThorsAnvil::Crypto
{

using Byte      = char unsigned;
using DigestPtr = Byte*;

template<typename Hash>
using Digest = typename Hash::DigestStore;

template<std::size_t size>
class DigestStore
{
    std::array<Byte, size>      data;
    public:
        using iterator = typename std::array<Byte, size>::iterator;

        operator Digest()                           {return &data[0];}
        std::string_view  view()                    {return std::string_view(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(&data[0]), std::size(data));}
        Byte&             operator[](std::size_t i) {return data[i];}
        iterator          begin()                   {return std::begin(data);}
        iterator          end()                     {return std::end(data);}
};

// These versions of the hashing function are good for hashing short
// amounts of text. Use these for passwords and validation hashes
// do not use them for hashing large documents.
struct Sha1
{
    static constexpr std::size_t digestSize = SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH;
    using DigestStore = DigestStore<SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH>;

    void hash(DigestStore& src,             DigestStore& dst)   {THOR_SHA1(src, SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH, dst);}
    void hash(std::string_view src,         DigestStore& dst)   {THOR_SHA1(reinterpret_cast<Byte const*>(&src[0]), std::size(src), dst);}
    void hash(std::string const& src,       DigestStore& dst)   {THOR_SHA1(reinterpret_cast<Byte const*>(&src[0]), std::size(src), dst);}
    // Use only if you know the destination is large enough!!
    void hashUnsafe(std::string_view src,   DigestPtr dst)      {THOR_SHA1(reinterpret_cast<Byte const*>(&src[0]), std::size(src), dst);}
};
struct Sha256
{
    static constexpr std::size_t digestSize = SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH;
    using DigestStore = DigestStore<SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH>;

    void hash(DigestStore& src,             DigestStore& dst)   {THOR_SHA256(src, SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH, dst);}
    void hash(std::string_view src,         DigestStore& dst)   {THOR_SHA256(reinterpret_cast<Byte const*>(&src[0]), std::size(src), dst);}
    void hash(std::string const& src,       DigestStore& dst)   {THOR_SHA256(reinterpret_cast<Byte const*>(&src[0]), std::size(src), dst);}
    // Use only if you know the destination is large enough!
    void hashUnsafe(std::string_view src,   Digestptr dst)      {THOR_SHA256(reinterpret_cast<Byte const*>(&src[0]), std::size(src), dst);}
};

}

#endif
```

Comment: @Emma I had not. Looks like I will need to start using one of those. But I just hate reading these badly written C++ (which is why I started this hack) projects that are crappy wrappers around C rather than using good type safety and nice clean C++ interfaces and techniques. Though I did enjoy writting these if I do any hard core stuff I will definetly use a proper library but these simple classes will let me do some quick checks (which is currently writting a C++ Mongo interface (and yes I know one exists but I can write a better one). Using ThorsSerializer to automate the serialization.

Comment: `too clean`. I'll take it.

Comment: @Emma: Priority 1: Impossible (or really hard for the user to break) to break. 2: Ease of use. 3: Speed.

Answer (score 3):

## Proper capitalization of SHA1

The algorithm's name is SHA1, not Sha1, so I think it is better to use all caps here. That makes grepping the code for a particular algorithm easier.

## You only need one class per hash algorithm

Indeed, as you mentioned in your own answer, the `Sha1` class seems superfluous, since it doesn't store any state. However, instead of creating static functions inside a `Sha1` namespace, you could make those functions member functions of the class that holds the actual state. This avoids repeating the type; for example:

```
Sha1::DigestStore digest;
Sha1::hash("Bob", digest)
```

Becomes:

```
Sha1::DigestStore digest;
digest.hash("Bob");
```

## `Sha1::Digest` vs. `Digest<Sha1>`

I think having a namespace `Sha1` with a `DigestStore` and functions inside it is a bad choice. There is more you can do with SHA1 than just create plain hashes, for example you might want to create a [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) instead of a plain hash. So you would have to add functions to create a HMAC to each namespace that implements a hash algorithm. It's much better to have classes `Digest` and `HMAC` that are templated on the hash algorithm.

## Allow hashes to be updated

The code you wrote only performs one-shot conversions of some input to a hash. However, it is not uncommon for programs to not have all the data they want to create a hash for in a single, contiguous memory region. In those cases, you want to write:

```
std::ostream output;
Digest<SHA1> digest;

digest.add("Header");
digest.add("Data");
digest.add("Footer");

output << digest.view();
```

Some digest algorithms might require you to call some function to calculate the final hash value after adding all the data. You could add an explicit `finish()` function or call this implicitly when accessing the digest result.

## Getting the result out

You internally store the hash as a `std::array<std::byte, size>`. That's the proper thing to do. I don't think it is necessary to provide any member functions other than one that gets you a `const` reference to that array. It's up to the caller to convert it to whatever form they way. A `std::array` is already implicitly convertible to a `std::span`. And once you have a reference to the array, it's easy to get the begin and end iterators from it.

## Add comparison operators

It's quite common to want to check whether two hashes are identical, so it would be helpful to at least define `operator==()` and `operator!=()` to the class that holds the digest result.

Comment: I had to think about it overnight. But I think I like the idea of putting the `hash()` method on the `Digest` object. Not 100% sure how to design it yet. But look for a review soon. :-)

Comment: I wanted to name the types `SHA1` but an all uppercase name makes my skin crawl (thinking of Macros). Not sure how to proceed here, I have to overcome my dread.

Comment: I was planning on adding an ability to update (add more text) as its a common feature for hashing. Currently I did not do it because I was only doing it for short pieces of text not document sized text. But long term that is definitely something I want to add; I just don't have a use case that I can experiment on with the interface.

Answer (score 1):

I think I am going to change the interface.

Currently the usage patter is:

```
typename Sha1::DigestStore      digest;
Sha1                            hasher;

hasher.hash("Bob", digest);
```

There does not seem a need to create a `Sha1` object. I think a better interface may be to make all the methods `static` so the usage becomes:

```
typename Sha1::DigestStore      digest;

Sha1::hash("Bob", digest);
```

The `DigestStore` may need some other accesses functions. It currently allows `iteration` but there can be a use case where we have a `const_iterator`.

Still trying to understand when best to use `string_view`. Unfortunately it still does not play well with normal strings. So we may have to provide a way to also extract a string from the buffer. In that case it would be nice if we could have the data from the DigestStore into a string (which means not using `std::array`) but need to have a good use case to make that work better.

Not sure how that will work yet. Please provide a hint if you have am idea.