# C++ Crypto:Part 3-pbkdf2

Tags: c++, cryptography, authentication, server, client

Looking around for modern Crypto libraries.
Could not find anything good.

I know I probably did this all wrong so work with me here. There will be four different reviews for four structures that build on each other:

1. [Hashing](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/248416/507)
2. [Hashed Key](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/248417/507)
3. Password Key
4. [Salted Challenge Response](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/248419/507)

This review is for an implementation of pbkdf2 implementation. This is a way of using HMAC that allows you to make incrementally more expensive to create the hash on failures. The idea is that you can slow down attacks by making it harder to make lots of guesses.

The data structures and implementation presented in these questions are based on [RFC2104](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2104) and this post on [codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22118/C-Class-Implementation-of-HMAC-SHA).

### Usage Example

```
Digest<Pbkdf2<HMac<Sha1>>>    digest;
Pbkdf2<HMac<Sha1>>            pbkdf2;

pbkdf2.hash("The password", "A Salt", 2048, digest);
```

### pbkdf2.h

```
#ifndef THORS_ANVIL_CRYPTO_PBKDF2_H
#define THORS_ANVIL_CRYPTO_PBKDF2_H

#include "hmac.h"
#include <string>

// RFC-2898 PKCS #5: Password-Based Cryptography Specification Version 2.0

namespace ThorsAnvil::Crypto
{

// Look in hmac.h for good examples of PRF
// ThorsAnvil::Crypto::HMac
template<typename PRF>
struct Pbkdf2
{
    static constexpr std::size_t digestSize = PRF::digestSize;
    using DigestStore    = typename PRF::DigestStore;

    void hash(std::string const& password, std::string const& salt, long iter, DigestStore& digest)
    {
#pragma vera-pushoff
        using namespace std::string_literals;
#pragma vera-pop
        PRF             prf;
        DigestStore     tmp;

        prf.hash(password, salt + "\x00\x00\x00\x01"s, tmp);
        std::copy(std::begin(tmp), std::end(tmp), std::begin(digest));

        for (int loop = 1; loop < iter; ++loop)
        {
            prf.hash(password, tmp.view(), tmp);
            for (std::size_t loop = 0; loop < digestSize; ++loop)
            {
                digest[loop] = digest[loop] ^ tmp[loop];
            }
        }
    }
};

}

#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void hash(std::string const& password, std::string const& salt, long iter, DigestStore& digest)
...
for (int loop = 1; loop < iter; ++loop)
        ...
        for (std::size_t loop = 0; loop < digestSize; ++loop)
```

"A `long` an `int` and a `std::size_t` all walked into a bar..." couldn't they all be `std::size_t`?

Also, overriding the `loop` variable is unnecessarily confusing.

---

```
    std::copy(std::begin(tmp), std::end(tmp), std::begin(digest));
```

I feel like this could just be `digest = tmp;` with an appropriate assignment operator.

---

```
salt + "\x00\x00\x00\x01"s
```

Could this be a named constant (or even a named function)? Or maybe add a comment to explain why this is here.

---

```
            digest[loop] = digest[loop] ^ tmp[loop];
```

Nitpick: could use `^=`

---

Perhaps the output should be a return value, not written to a reference?

---

I don't know enough about cryptography / security to assess the algorithm / safety aspects of this.